# Морфемный разбор

Tags: словообразование, словоизменение, морфемика, учебное-задание, морфология

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать морфемный разбор следующий слов: 
по типу: перечитывание - перечитывать - перечитать - читать (то есть чтобы показать каждую морфему). 
В некоторых словах знаю как делать, но хотелось бы удостовериться,  так как не уверена,
помогите составить эту цепочку...

Безделушки

Окрашивание

Располагающаяся

Простиралась

Исследование

Приграничная

Поэтапное

Обнаруженный

Изготовление

Примыкающие

Вырезанный

**Обновление**

первый не знаю

окрашивание - окрашивать - окрасить - красить

располагающаяся - располагающая - располагать - полагать

четвертый не знаю

исследование - исследовать (не знаю, как до конца)

приграничная - граничить (не полная тоже)

поэтапное - этапное - этап

Обнаруженный - обнаружение - обнаружить ( тоже не знаю как до конца)

изготовление - подготавливать - готовить

примыкающие - примыкать (не знаю, как до конца)

вырезанный - вырезать - резать

Comment: Не выйдет, напишите свои варианты,а мы проверим

Comment: первый не знаю

Comment: А как это? Вроде только 4 комментария может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

без/дел/ушк/и - дел/о - дел/а/ть (Именно так - дело образовалось от глагола делать)

Простиралась - простираться - простирать

исслед/ова/ни/е - исслед/ова/ть

приграничная - границ/а

по/этап/н/ое - этап (этапное и поэтапное - не цепочка, они параллельно образовались от этап). Поэтапное - приставочно-суффиксальный способ. (Поэтапное планирование - планирование по отдельным этапам)

Обнаруж/енн/ый -  обнаруж/и/ть

изготовление - из/готов/и/ть - готов/и/ть

примыкающие - при/мык/а/ть

вырезанный - вырезать - резать

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Не все слова образуются по цепочке. Например, Обнаружить 
- обнаружение. Обнаружить 
- обнаруженный.